# How can I select elements which don't contain anchors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to conduct some action while clicking a certain 'tr', yet within that object I would like jQuery to ignore one of the children td which contains a url.. Any ideas how can this be done?

```
<tr class="parent_report>
 <tr class="child1">Some text</tr>
 <tr class="child2">Some text</tr>
 <tr class="child3"><span><a href="./">Some text</a></span></tr>
</tr>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(".special_report, .new_report ,.parent_report").not("span").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();    
 //do some action
```

So I would like to ignore the jQuery when clicking the link in child3 and not doing the action configured to jQuery

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I've attempted using not() but for some reason it did not work.. maybe it's the multiple selection..

Comment: There's no code referencing ajax ([`jQuery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`). Do you mean jQuery itself?

Comment: Your code says that the element that you are selecting can not be a span.

Comment: Code has nothing to do with Ajax, wherever you mentioned Ajax, I changed it to jQuery... Some of it is still not right, but it is still better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying that any of the classes you selected can not be a span. You are not saying what is clicked....

So you need to do the check inside of the click that the action is not an anchor

```js
$("tr").on("click", function (evt) {
  if ($(evt.target).closest("a").length) {
    return true
  } else {
    console.log("tr was clicked");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>baz</td>
      <td class="child3"><span><a href="./">Some text</a></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you do not want any click on the td, than just ignore clicks on that td

```js
$("tr").on("click", "td:not(:has(a))", function(evt) {
  console.log("tr was clicked");
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>baz</td>
      <td class="child3"><span><a href="./">Some text</a></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Add some padding to all data cells and you can click outside the anchor.

Comment: I read it they should not click on an anchor.... so if they do not want to click on the cell at all, it is not much different....

Answer (score 0):

I'd move your click events to the table cells for more intuitive code.

```js
$("td").not(':has("a")').click(function () {
    console.log("tr was clicked");
});
```

```html
<style>
td {
    padding: 10px;
    background: pink;
}
a {
    background: lightgreen;
}
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>baz</td>
      <td class="child3"><span><a href="javascript:void(0)">Some text</a></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```